# How get source code of files in a commit with GitPython?

Tags: python, git, file, commit, gitpython

I need to get source codes for all files in a commit. Currently I am using Pydriller and it works well. But for performance reasons I need to use GitPython.
I have tried this solution:

```
repo = Repo('path to repo') )
    commit = repo.commit('my hash')
with io.BytesIO(target_file.data_stream.read()) as f: 
    print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Programmi\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
File "D:\Programmi\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "D:/Workspaces/PythonProjects/fixing- 
    commit/crop_data_preparing_gitpython.py", line 82, in 
get_commit_data_gitpython
print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9f in position 18: invalid start byte
```

I have thought that this can be an encoding problem, but even changing the encoding from utf-8 to latin-1 doesn't help.

Does exist another strategy that would help me get the code for those files using GitPython?

Comment: `PyDriller` uses `GitPython`, so with a little searching, I think you can find happiness.

Comment: For a relative path path/to/foo.bar, try `repo.git.show('%s:%s' % (commit.hexsha, 'path/to/foo.bar'))`.